# Azure Container Groups and Later Swapping One of the Containers in the Container Group

Tags: azure-container-instances

When you deploy an azure container group ("Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"), can you replace just one of the containers at a ***later*** time?

Or does the creation of the container_group have to have all the containers at the time of creation (of the container group) ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-multi-container-group

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "[parameters('resourceGroupName')]",
      "type": "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups",
      "apiVersion": "2018-06-01",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "properties": {
        "containers": [
          {
            "name": "[parameters('loggingContainerName')]",
            "properties": {
              "image": "[parameters('loggingContainerImage')]",
              "resources": {
                "requests": {
                  "cpu": 1,
                  "memoryInGb": 1
                }
              },
              "volumeMounts": [
                {
                  "name": "[parameters('volumeName')]",
                  "mountPath": "/aci/logs/"
                }
              ],
              "ports": [
                {
                  "port": 8080
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[parameters('jobGeneratorContainerName')]",
            "properties": {
              "image": "[parameters('jobGeneratorContainerImage')]",
              "resources": {
                "requests": {
                  "cpu": 1,
                  "memoryInGb": 1
                }
              },
              "ports": [
                {
                  "port": 80
                }
              ],
              "volumeMounts": [
                {
                  "name": "[parameters('volumeName')]",
                  "mountPath": "/aci/logs/"
                }
              ],
              "environmentVariables": [
                {
                  "name": "ServiceBusConnectionString",
                  "value": "[parameters('serviceBusConnectionStringSend')]"
                },
                {
                  "name": "LoggingServiceUrl",
                  "value": "[parameters('loggingServiceUrl')]"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "[parameters('jobProcessingContainerName')]",
            "properties": {
              "image": "[parameters('jobProcessingContainerImage')]",
              "resources": {
                "requests": {
                  "cpu": 1,
                  "memoryInGb": 1
                }
              },
              "ports": [
                {
                  "port": 8000
                }
              ],
              "environmentVariables": [
                {
                  "name": "ServiceBusConnectionString",
                  "value": "[parameters('serviceBusConnectionStringListen')]"
                },
                {
                  "name": "LoggingServiceUrl",
                  "value": "[parameters('loggingServiceUrl')]"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        "osType": "Linux",
        "ipAddress": {
          "type": "Public",
          "ports": [
            {
              "protocol": "tcp",
              "port": "80"
            },
            {
              "protocol": "TCP",
              "port": 443
            }
          ],
          "dnsNameLabel": "[uniqueString( resourceGroup().id )]"
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

As I know, what you said is right. The top level in Azure container instances is container group. No matter one or more than one container instances you want to create in a container group, you should create it or them in one time.

If the container group is created, you cannot change it, such as adding containers or changing container images. If you really want, you just can create a new one.

**By the way**, the multi-container group only support for Linux containers.